# While loop only works when webpage is opened locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a function that makes sure an image is both big enough horizontally and vertically to fill it's parent element, and to do this I used a while loop. When I open the index.html file on my computer locally it loads fine but as soon as I upload it to my server and try to access it the page never loads.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     initialize();
}

function initialize() {
    $("[data-type='parallax']").each(function() {
         $(this).css('height', $(this).parent().height());
         while (($(this).height() < $(this).parent().height()) || ($(this).width() <  $(this).parent().width())) {
              $(this).css('height', '+=1px');
         }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know why this is? I know it's the while loop I just don't understand why it works locally. Is there an easier way to approach this with CSS where the image is at least as tall and wide as the parent element but only as big as it needs to be.

Comment: Why are you even using a `while` loop? You can just use an `if` statement.

Comment: are you refering the jquery locally?

Comment: Tried window.load instead of doc.ready?

Comment: If that's your actual code, your `.ready` call is not closed properly. Should be `});`

Comment: Also you might want to look into using `.animate()` instead of trying to animate with a while loop: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I'm using a while instead of an if because the if will only run once, where as the while will continue to run until it's the right size.

Comment: Couldn't you just figure out the difference in height between the parent and child and add that to the height? You wouldn't need a loop or even an if statement. Also do you know that any of your jquery is working at all when you upload to the server? It might just be a bad jquery path.

Comment: The problem is I need both the height and width to be larger than the parent element but if I specify both then it loses its aspect ratio.

Comment: How about `$(this).css('min-height', $(this).parent().height() + 'px'); $(this).css('min-width', $(this).parent().width() + 'px')`?

Comment: My images are very large so they will always meet that min-height/min-width and remain too big. I want them to only be as big as they need to be.

Comment: Oh I thought you said "I need both the height and width to be larger than the parent element". If you want it to be smaller, try `max-height` / `max-width`?

Comment: They need to be at least as large, but only as large as it needs to be. So if the image is 100x200 and it's contained by a div thats 300x500 then the width needs to be set to 300 and the height will be whatever it needs to be in order to maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

you could use animate, check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/fnhwA/)
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     initialize();
})
function initialize() {
    $("[data-type='parallax']").each(function() {
        var wi=$(this).width()
        var he=$(this).height()
        var pW=$(this).parent().width()
        var pH=$(this).parent().height()
        if(wi<pW||he<pH){
            $(this).animate({'width':pW+'px','height':pH+'px'},1000)
            } 
    });
}   
</script>
```